# Не проходит клик по View, лежащим под foreground, ItemTouchHelper.Callback

Tags: android, itemtouchhelper

В проекте используется RecyclerView для которого нужно реализовать поведение сдвига элемента по свайпу. Под элементом находится кнопка удаления

layout для элемента выглядит так

```
<layout>
    <background/>
    <foreground/>
</layout>
```

определяю Callback

```
public class MovingForwgroundTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    public MovingForwgroundTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            if (viewHolder != null && viewHolder instanceof MovingForegroundViewHolder) {

                MovingForegroundViewHolder vh = (MovingForegroundViewHolder) viewHolder;
                final View foregroundView = vh.getForeground();
                final float maxOffset = vh.getMaxOffset();
                final float screenWidth = SystemBarTintManager.screenWidth(recyclerView.getContext());

                getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX * (maxOffset / screenWidth), dY,
                        actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        } else {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    }

}
```

подсовываю его ресайклеру

```
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new MovingForwgroundTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

В итоге сдвиг работает превосходно, но по клику на item (в любом месте, в т.ч. когда кликаю на кнопку, для которой назначен listener для удаления элемента) сдвинутый foreground возвращается назад, и удаления не происходит.

Я первый раз работаю с ItemTouchHelper, возможно я пропускаю что то очевидное. Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно добавить в эту схему, чтобы она работала.

Мне не нужен код, который это делает, а нужен хороший совет по теории, потому что я пока просто не знаю в каком направлении копать. Полный код проекта привести не могу, но уточняйте, может удастся добавить какие то моменты.

Comment: Там вроде получается так, что `foreground` перекрывает `background` даже когда сдвинут. Я бы попробовал сделать его неактивным после свайпа в методе **onSwiped**.

Comment: И еще, когда этим занимался, пришел к выводу, что для одного действия (одной кнопки) лучше использовать обычный свайп с прорисовкой кнопки без макетов. Это решает большинство проблем.

Comment: @kulikovman насчёт перекрывания вариант отпадает, я навесил OnClickListener на foreground с логом, он не отрабатывает. Не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду во втором варианте. Что то вроде рисования имитации кнопки на канвасе и отрабатывания клика по определенным координатам ресайклера?

Comment: насколько я понял, это называется **swipe-to-dismiss**. Там нужное действие выполняется в **onSwiped**, в зависимости от направления свайпа. Вместо кнопки, в **onChildDraw** закрашивается фон и рисуется пояснительная иконка или надпись. Вот пример - https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/custom-swipe-recyclerview.html

Comment: @kulikovman большое спасибо